How to restructure a treemap graph in R so that categories, subcategories and values are visible
I need create treemap plot,here my data
fd=structure(list(geo = c("FR", "ID", "KE", "NG", "TH", "BD", "BF", 
"GB", "ID", "US", "DE", "FR", "GB", "US", "ZA", "BR", "DE", "GB", 
"IN", "US", "GB", "KR", "TR", "US", "UZ", "AU", "CA", "CI", "SN", 
"TH", "DE", "FR", "GB", "ID", "US", "DE", "GB", "SA", "TH", "US"
), total_gross = c(74800.179198648, 206351.720296498, 87104.011204479, 
230279.098284536, 88416.123570242, 30649.923307, 1797.704424, 
7203.416263, 20182.697799371, 1248.065576, 3884.255650215, 4312.951986, 
7590.300395, 6124.868841, 5223.464131, 8579.658550893, 5105.435153999, 
7041.527072472, 28142.360652436, 34010.800759784, 2274.429363, 
1032.775403, 3611.359533, 27850.021229, 21428.923638, 3428.672326, 
1596.969545249, 3506.142073, 1137.637902, 1932.374443, 7028.91663786, 
9778.256711419, 6271.898612455, 5442.656310329, 47786.935549483, 
46615.8912281, 34268.94122415, 20576.448612643, 20973.696070114, 
288397.397156119), dataset = c("data0_50", "data0_50", "data0_50", 
"data0_50", "data0_50", "data10001_50000", "data10001_50000", 
"data10001_50000", "data10001_50000", "data10001_50000", "data1001_5000", 
"data1001_5000", "data1001_5000", "data1001_5000", "data1001_5000", 
"data101_500", "data101_500", "data101_500", "data101_500", "data101_500", 
"data50001", "data50001", "data50001", "data50001", "data50001", 
"data5001_10000", "data5001_10000", "data5001_10000", "data5001_10000", 
"data5001_10000", "data501_1000", "data501_1000", "data501_1000", 
"data501_1000", "data501_1000", "data51_100", "data51_100", "data51_100", 
"data51_100", "data51_100"), perc = c(4L, 8L, 18L, 14L, 5L, 3L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))

I create treemap, it's important for me to see the perc in each category of the dataset + geo subcategories of this dataset.
I do this
fd=read.csv("C:/1/fd.csv",dec=".",sep=";")
str(fd)

# Install required packages if they are not installed
if (!require(treemap)) {
   install.packages("treemap")
   library(treemap)
}

# Convert data into a format suitable for treemap
treemap_data <- aggregate(perc ~ geo + dataset, data = fd, sum)

# Building treemap
treemap(treemap_data, index=c("geo", "dataset"), vSize="perc", vColor="perc")

------------------------
   # Set image size
   png("treemap.png", width = 3200, height = 2400, res = 1000) # Change the size and resolution to your liking

# Building treemap
treemap(treemap_data, index=c("geo", "dataset"), vSize="perc", vColor="perc")

# Closing the output device
dev.off()

as the result i get
completely unreadable chart

the names of geo and datasets are mixed up, and there is no exact value for the metric perс variable
How to do that each square contains the name of the geo, the name of the dataset and its perc value
example like this

here is the dataset, geo and perс value.
Thank you for your help.

You could paste the 3 elements together with a line-break between them:
library(treemap)

treemap_data <- aggregate(perc ~ geo + dataset, data = fd, sum) |> 
  dplyr::mutate(label = paste0(geo, "\n", dataset, "\n", perc))

treemap(treemap_data, index = "label", vSize="perc", vColor="perc", 
        fontsize.labels = 6, align.labels = c("left", "top"))

﻿﻿﻿
